# Can snap access PulseAudio without snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio.service?

Tags: pulseaudio, snap

I installed [vokoscreenNG](https://snapcraft.io/vokoscreen-ng) as snap and found out that installing pulseaudio (`snap install pulseaudio`) is [required to capture audio](https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreenNG/issues/52).

To the best of my knowledge, PulseAudio comes preinstalled with Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. Does it mean that there are two concurrent sound services, one for the system and one for snaps?

Finally, can snap use PulseAudio from the system directly? I found some [documentation to connect snap to the PulseAudio service](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/audio/pulseaudio/docs/access-from-other-snaps) but I am not sure if this applies to PulseAudio from the system.

Comment: Do you insist on using the snap version of the app? If no, I can post an answer.

Comment: Yes, the question is about snap and how it uses sound services. The given example with vokoscreenNG only provides some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to answer your questions

> To the best of my knowledge, PulseAudio comes preinstalled with Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. Does it mean that there are two concurrent sound services, one for the system and one for snaps?

Yes, PulseAudio comes preinstalled with Ubuntu 18.04 and running second PulseAudio instance in snap is not recommended (source: https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/audio/pulseaudio/docs/install-pulseaudio)

> Finally, can snap use PulseAudio from the system directly?

Yes, in order to do that you can use the following command

```
snap connect vokoscreen-ng:pulseaudio
```

**Edit**

Regarding the Github issue, the reporter of the issue seems to be using Ubuntu Core, a version of Ubuntu that doesn't come preinstalled with PulseAudio and use snap package as the primary way of app packaging

Comment: Hi there - reporter of the GH issue here:) Just to clarify, I've never actually attempted to do a `snap connect` in any of the phases, as detailed in https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management. I *did* have `pulseaudio` installed before, though, so I'm not sure about that last comment. I did not install it manually, to the best of my recollection.